# Flutter Layout 3 Columns Wide 3 Rows Deep with Icon and Text Below - Icons OnPressed (Not Navbar but Full Screen)

Tags: flutter, layout, navigation, icons, clickable

New(er) to Flutter and self-learning. Have tried multiple methods but haven't found the "best option".

See screenshot. I need to produce something similar to this mockup.

Need Icons 3 or 4 wide and multiple rows down with Icons and Text centered below. The Icons need an OnPressed or other actionable code to navigate to another screen/view. The text does not necessarily need to be clickable.

I would appreciate some guidance as to where to begin. Some links or code exmaple would be great but really want to know I'm on the right track with the best possible solution to creating a similar screen.

Thank you in advance.

[image: I Need This :)]

```
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/logic/custom_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'package:welakaone/navigation/route.dart' as route;

class DirectoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DirectoryScreenState createState() => _DirectoryScreenState();
}

class _DirectoryScreenState extends State<DirectoryScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(
        uid: '',
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
                CustomColors.welakaoneBlueDark,
              ],
              begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: FractionalOffset(1.6, 1.0),
              stops: [0.3, 1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            ),
          ),
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            onPressed: () {},
            // child: Container(
            //   height: 100,
            //   width: 200,
            //   child: Column(
            //     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            //     children: <Widget>[
            //       Padding(
            //         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            //         child: Icon(
            //           Icons.camera,
            //           color: Colors.white,
            //         ),
            //       ),
            //       Padding(
            //         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            //         child: Text(
            //           "Capture from Camera",
            //           style: TextStyle(
            //             color: Colors.yellow,
            //             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            //           ),
            //         ),
            //       ),
            //     ],
            //   ),
            // ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down your problem to two smaller problems

1. Create 3 Column wide 3 rows of `SomeWidget`
2. Create a clickable widget for the above layout.

---

Solutions:

1st Problem : Flutter got a dedicated widget to layout grid like structures called [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html). Use that to create 3x3 Grid on that page.

2nd Problem : Use `Column` widget to show an icon and a text beneath that. Then, make the entire thing clickable with either wrapping that column with [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) or [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: Thank you! There is probably a shorter path to get the results I want but the code works for me!

Answer (score 0):

After working on solution offered by HasilT I came up with this code which works for me. There may be a "shorter" way to get to where I wanted to be but this code does the job! Thank you HasilT... I learned something today thanks to you.

I will add the code for InkWell next.

```
import 'package:welakaone/appbar/app_bar_title.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/logic/custom_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'package:welakaone/navigation/route.dart' as route;

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
        title: AppBarTitle(),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(
        uid: '',
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              CustomColors.welakaoneBlack,
              CustomColors.welakaoneBlueDark,
            ],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: FractionalOffset(1.6, 1.0),
            stops: [0.3, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
          ),
        ),
        child: GridView.count(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: false,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 1',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.login,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 3',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 4',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.door_back_door,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 5',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.place,
                      size: 80,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'TEST 6',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This Is Result]